# PowerBI: Tooltip using Date/Time and information

Tags: excel, powerbi, business-intelligence, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I hope that some of you are familiar with Tooltips in PowerBI and their purpose. Therefore, I would like to ask if it is possible to make a tooltip from the data that I copied down here?!

Lets say that I have one set of data (report) where you got exactly the same data format (date/time/info), but their saved in `.txt` and what I actually wanna is somehow "make" them to work on my charts for that given date/time? I am only able to hover over some data and see whole bunch of data but not exactly for that period (I cant even scroll when the data are just showed in PBI Tooltip).

I managed to extract the date and time using PowerQuery Editor in PBI, but the info part stayed questionable, how or is it possible at all to combine it somehow so I can use it as great tooltip which can say for instance; "okay, on that date you changed system, what is actually visible from the chart", but I would like to have it originally from the "report" aka. tooltip!

Hope you got my question, just wandering if that is possible to do in PBI?

Thx

```
2019-01-09|13:18:59|Operation Mode C1->C2                                                                  |
2019-01-09|13:19:22|User logged out: ACC2                                                                  |
2019-01-09|13:19:28|User logged in: ACC2                                                                   |
2019-01-09|13:19:31|User logged out: ACC2                                                                  |
```

here are two photos of what I actually see:
[image]

and something I wanna see:
[image]

I did this by excluding the line from the Tooltip, but that isnt efficient at all, because there are thousands of lines

Any idea how to convert this txt date format into normal data (date) type? I tried with `.datefromtext` but it didnt work... gives errors all the time. Any other way using M language or?? Normal change of data type also didnt work...maybe regional settings but not sure... 
[image]

Comment: That depends... Can you post a sample what your chart should look like (x/y-values and the tooltip)? Depending on that you can just drag and drop your column/measure into the tooltip section of your visual or you can make a custom tooltip.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub I did include 2x pics..

Comment: Ok, let me know if I got that right. Your charts x-axis are months. And you have per month/day a lot of data (like in your table example above), which are to much to display in a tooltip? At this point you could either do a drill down in your chart (from month to day), thus the tooltip info would be less (just for that day then) or you create a subreport (drillthrough) which jumps to another report page with the tooltips detail data.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub X-axis shows Month/day/time, all of the time values, but they are compressed cuz of big data ,and it shows months only. 

But look, the data itself in report (tooltip) dont they need to be converted to some accessible file for PBI - theyre exactly as you see them, long text file with " I " between them. As far as I know it has to be converted at first point so I can use them? Chart cant read this Tooltip just if plugged.. 

Or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Edit Queries > Home > Split Column > Split Column by Delimiter` with the following settings:

[image]

You will get the following result:

[image]

Now rename the column names and make sure the columns have the right data type. If your relationship is set, you now can show and customize a better tooltip.

Comment: I actually almost did it like this, but you think this will work like if they are "merged" after relationship?

Comment: That depends how your table setup/design is. If you have two separate tables you could merge them. You also can just create a relationship between this two tables. Both ways will work.

Comment: Hmm stucked on converting txt  date to normal type of date... any idea? I included pic..

Comment: The converting for me works at this example. But you can still work with `Date.FromText("2010-10-12")` or you can split the date parts by dilimiter and use this `Date.FromText("2010, 12, 31")`

Comment: Thx man! With a help of you I got something actually even better...that goes amazingly with timescale. I managed to convert the data (used CLEAN function in Editor) and then automatically converted into Date. 

Importantly, we can quit this topic! I got an idea for the further job!